# Merge two dfs with duplicate rows, except in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a panda data frame (after concatenating two dataframes) which has some duplicate rows, except two columns, where some row identifier are written. E.g.

```
  A      B C D E F
  Peter  1 c d e f
  Paula  2 g h i j
  Frank  3 c d e f
  Robert 4 k l m n
  Sarah  5 g h i j
```

use for testing:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"A":["Peter", "Paula", "Frank", "Robert", "Sara"],
                  "B":[1,2,3,4,5],
                  "C":["c","g","c","k","g"],
                  "D":["d","h","d","l","h"],
                  "E":["e","i","e","m","i"],
                  "F":["f","j","f","n","j"]})
```

I want to keep only the first appearance of the duplicates in the colums C to F and keep the name and number (columns "A" and "B") of that rows. Thus, we would gain

```
  A      B C D E F
  Peter  1 c d e f
  Paula  2 g h i j
  Robert 4 k l m n
```

I tried something out with df.drop_duplicates, but that does not work with excluding rows "A" and "B". Also, when separating into two dataframes with A and B, and C to D, drop_duplicate, and merge afterwards via the index does not work, since drop_duplicates resets the index. So, how to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, the solution was nearer than expected. I dropped the first two columns and extracted the colnames into a list, and then used this list as selected subset in the drop_duplicates function: `keys_cols=df.drop(["A","B"], axis=1).columns.tolist()
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=keys_cols)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["C", "D", "E", "F"])
```

Output:

```
        A  B  C  D  E  F
0   Peter  1  c  d  e  f
1   Paula  2  g  h  i  j
3  Robert  4  k  l  m  n
```

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: yes, thanks. That is the way, if you have specific names. The general approach, I have found out already, also.